# что надо передать в return view post django

Tags: python, django

что надо возвращать в return в post?
ошибка: *ValueError: The view plugins.views.ViewCurrentPlugins didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.*

**views.py**

```
class ViewCurrentPlugins(DetailView):
    model = Plugins
    context_object_name = 'plugins'
    template_name = 'plugins/plugins_detail_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'plugins_item'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tag'] = self.kwargs['tag']
        context['form'] = RelatedPluginForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = RelatedPluginForm(request.POST)
        related_id = request.POST['related']

        if form.is_valid():)
            self.plugin = self.get_object()
            self.plugin.related.add(related_id)                
            self.plugin.save()            
            return
        else:            
            return
```

Comment: [return HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно для этого примера больше подойдет `FormView`.
В крайнем случае, можно подсмотреть, что именно он возвращает пользователю.

Например в случае валидной формы:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

в случае провала, когда нужно заново сгенерировать страницу с этим контекстом:

```
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

только в Вашем случае, возможно, придется передавать все необходимые параметры для формирования контекста.
Так же можно дополнительно подправить метод `get_context_data`, заменив формирование формы для контекста, что бы данные введенные пользователем не терялись

```
context['form'] = kwargs.get('form', RelatedPluginForm())
```